# How can I configure NotifyOSD?

Tags: software-recommendation, configuration, notify-osd

Is there a way to configure NotifyOSD by using the terminal or an application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is What you are looking for

[Notifyconf in Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/notifyconf)

There was a story about it done on Webupdate last May [Here](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/05/gui-to-configure-notifyosd-in-ubuntu.html)

Its not a normal PPA the install instructions are as follows

You need to run each of these commands separately

```
bzr branch lp:notifyconf
cd notifyconf
make
sudo make install
```

After install it will be in your Accessories

Comment: Glad I could help Tarek